# How to compare with records given with in a Map

Tags: apex

I am having Map `calcPriceMap` with Key as product ID and value as `CalcPriceInfo` (Wrapper Class)

```
class OuterClass {

    Map<Id, CalcPriceInfo> calcPriceMap ; // Id= ProductID

    //Product2 SObject has 1 field current_Price__c

    //Inner Class    
    public class CalcPriceInfo {
       Decimal currentPrice;         
    }
}
```

I have `calcPriceMap`  with data. 
My question is it possible to compare Product's `current_Price__c` with `CalcPriceInfo` 's `currentPrice` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I see point of having wrapper class with just one value...

But to compare those try:

```
Product2[] p2s = /** some values**/;

for(Product2 p2 : p2s){
    if(calcPriceMap.containsKey(p2.Id) 
        &&p2.current_Price__c == calcPriceMap.get(p2.Id).currentPrice){
        /** do something **/
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually above is a pesudo code. Actual Wrapper class has 1 more variable and we are comparing that variable's value  with related product field's value.